# Displaying tables error argument to reversed () must be a sequence

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm developing a little app where I can display all the tables in my database (sqlite3) and, choosing one of them, visualize the data ( I know I can do that with the admin, but I need to se that in the app)

I have in my model.py different models, something like myModel1, myModel2...

In my views.py

```
def myhomepage(request):
    tables_list = connection.introspection.table_names() 
    return render(request, 'myhomepage.html', { 'tables_list': tables_list})

 def detail_table(request, table):
    try:
        Table_to_View = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="myapp", model=table)
    except Table_to_View.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404 ("La tabella non esiste")
    context = {'Table_to_View' : Table_to_View }
    return render(request, "detail_table.html", context )
```

and the template myhomepage.html

```
{#something#}
<title>Lista delle tabelle</title>
<body>
{% if tables_list %}
<ul>
{%for t in tables_list %}
  <li> <a href="{% url 'detail_table' t %}"> {{table}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

this is the urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = {
    url(r'^$', views.myhomepage, name='myhomepage'),
    url(r'^(?P<table>.*)/$', views.detail_table, name='detail_table'),
}
```

but it highlights this

```
{% url 'detail_table' t %}"
```

and gives me this error:

`argument to reversed () must be a sequence`

How can I resolve this?
Thank you.

ps: if there is any more clever way to do this, I accept advise!

[edit] adding the view detail_table and urls.py

Comment: It would help to see the urls.py or the view that `detail_table` calls

Comment: Please include the full traceback of the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `{}` instead of `[]` for your `urlpatterns`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.myhomepage, name='myhomepage'),
    url(r'^(?P<table>.*)/$', views.detail_table, name='detail_table'),
]
```

Square braces not curly.